# HexString & Hexadecimal

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me the difference between these two ? Looks similar but the output is different

```
    int b = 80 ;
    int a = Integer.parseInt(""+b, 16);
    int c = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(b));
```

Comment: [Reference the API for `Integer.toHexString()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int))

Comment: The first parses `"80"` as a hex representation of an integer, namely that which is `128` in decimal. The second converts what is `80` in decimal into its hex representation, i.e. `"50"` -- and then parses that into an integer whose decimal representation is `50`.

Answer (score 4):

`int a = Integer.parseInt(""+b, 16)` interprets `"80"` as a base 16 number and sets a to it's value (`128` in base 10).

`int c = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(b))` first converts `80` in base 10 to a base 16 number (which is `50`) and then interprets this a number in base 10- which is `50`.

Answer (score 0):

One converts to decimal and parses it as hexi-decimal.

The other converts to hexi-decimal and parses it as decimal.

If it doesn't make any sense that is a good thing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first expression, `Integer.parseInt(""+b, 16)` is parsing the value 80 as a hexadecimal number (0x80), resulting in the decimal number of 128.

The second expression `Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(b))` first converts the decimal number 80 to hexadecimal (`Integer.toHexString(b)`) resulting in the hexadecimal number 50 (0x50), which is then parsed as a decimal number, resulting in the decimal number 50.